# How to pass heredoc defined variable to command

Tags: shell

How can I pass this heredoc defined variable to a command?

```
read -r -d '' tables <<'EOF'
table1
table2
table3
EOF

tables=$(tr '\n' ' ' < "$tables");
```

I want the table variable to be defined as:

```
table1 table2 table3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash, you can use a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)

```
tables=$(tr '\n' ' ' <<< "$tables")
```

With other shells, you can use *another* here document

```
tables=$(tr '\n' ' ' << END
$tables
END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use a multi-line string.

```
tables="
table1
table2
table3"

echo $tables
for table in $tables; do echo $table; done
```

Your `heredoc` is treated equivalently on my system

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your multi-line variable you can just use `echo`:

```
echo "$tables" | tr '\n' ' '
```

Just be sure to use double quotes to *protect* the newlines. Compare:

```
$ echo $tables | tr '\n' '_'
table1 table2 table3_
```

with:

```
$ echo "$tables" | tr '\n' '_'
table1_table2_table3_
```